# Is LPAD allowed in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL script with a variable called v_credit_hours that is a number data type. I fetch my fields from a cursor and insert them into a table where the credit_hours field is also a number. I need to pad v_credit_hours with leading zeros and end up with four digits before inserting it. So 50 hours should like like 0050. I have this line just before my insert statement.

`v_credit_hours := LPAD(ROUND(v_credit_hours), 4, 0);`

The problem is that it does not change anything. 50 still comes out as 50. Nothing happens if I change 4 to 10 or if I remove LPAD completely. I tried changing v_credit_hours to v_credit_hours * 8 inside the ROUND, and that altered the result. It is as if Oracle is just ignoring LPAD. It comes out fine in this query, but not when I use PL/SQL. I also tried adding TO_CHAR between LPAD and ROUND, but that did nothing.

`SELECT LPAD(ROUND(50), 4, 0) FROM dual;`

Can I not use LPAD in this way? I can do it up in my original cursor, but I really only wanted to see the leading zeros in the final output.

Comment: LPAD returns a string (VARCHAR2). If you save it in a NUMBER variable, you immediately lose your formatting.

Comment: if v_credit_hours and credit_hours are -- _as they should be_ - typed as NUMBER, then the leading zeros is strictly a display issue.  NUMBER is an internal, binary construct and does not store leading zeros which are - in mathematical terms - "insiginficant digits".  If you want to SEE leading zeros, then pass your NUMBER through a properly constructed TO_CHAR function when you prepare it for human eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its sorta hard to tell if v_credit_hours is typed as a Number or a Varchar. However, if you do it this way you will get what you want.

```
 DECLARE
 v_formatted_credit_hours  varchar2(60);

BEGIN 

 SELECT lpad(round(50),4,0)
 INTO v_formatted_credit_hours
 FROM dual ;

SYS.dbms_output.put_line( v_formatted_credit_hours) ;

END;
```

hopefully that helps to shine a little light on your issue.

Comment: I sort of did it this way. I didn't realize it changes the datatype. So I changed the datatype in my table and had to create a new variable of varchar because a previous cursor is using the number v_credit_hours. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: so what was the data type in your table, and what did you change it to?  As I said earlier, numbers should be stored as NUMBER (and dates should be store as DATE).  And all internal operations (comparisons, etc) should be done as NUMBER.  You can and should _only_ convert it to character strings (VARCHAR2, etc) when you need to display it to a human.